# .finish() is not working inside a nested if statement

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason, I cant use .finish() to end my previous activity inside a nested if statement.

```
if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
        MenuFragment menuFragment = MenuFragment.newInstance("", "");
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.layout_for_fragment,
                menuFragment
        ).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_report) {
        if(status == 1){
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logout();
            getApplicationContext().finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should not even compile.  If this code is in an Activity, just call `this.finish()`

Comment: Also if you use   getApplicationContext() for new Intent you need to set flag to -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: just call finish as long as you are in an activity main class and call MyActivity.this.finish() when you are an inner class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getApplicationContext().finish();` it is context. Use `ClassNameYourActivity.this.finish();`